# How do I stub AJAX requests whose response depends on data passed?

Tags: javascript, ajax, unit-testing, jasmine, client-side

I'm trying to do unit testing with Jasmine. I need to mock two AJAX GET requests to the same URL but whose responses depend on the data passed in the request. So far I've been unable to find any information on how to make the response depend on anything but the URL.

I've been trying to use the `stubRequest` method:

```
   jasmine.Ajax.stubRequest('MY_URL.json')
      .andReturn({
        "status": 200,
        "contentType": 'application/json',
        "responseText": rawData
      });
```

I should also mention that the AJAX requests are made in an arbitrary order. Also the data passed is just a single parameter.

Comment: What is used as a backend for these requests? You need to test how your backend handles different requests right? Or you need to stub a backend for your requests?

Comment: @dajnz, no, these are front-end/client-side unit tests; the backend is exactly what I want to omit from these tests. Backend tests are a separate thing in our system.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Nodejs-based environment, then this [library](https://github.com/nock/nock) will help you.

This example depicts how to return different responses depending on request data using the library:

```js
const myRequestStub = nock('http://my-domain.tld')
  .post('/some/request/path')
  .reply(201, (uri, requestBody) => {
    // Here you can do what you want and return response depending on the request
    return [
      // Response HTTP code
      201,
      // Response
      'this is my custom response body',
      // optional headers
      { header: 'value' },
    ];
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, @dajnz. Could you please clarify how one can use a NodeJS library for client-side testing?

Answer (score 0):

The online documentation is pretty sparse, but I found the method definition (Jasmine v3.4.0), which answers my question:

```
this.stubRequest = function(url, data, method) {
  var stub = new $ajax.RequestStub(url, data, method);
  stubTracker.addStub(stub);
  return stub;
};
```

The `data` argument is an object with keys and values being the URL parameters and values.

```
jasmine.Ajax.stubRequest('MY_URL.json', {param1: "value1"}, "GET")
  .andReturn({
    "status": 200,
    "contentType": 'application/json',
    "responseText": rawData
  });
```

Or so, I thought. Actually, while that might work for POST, for the GET request I'm trying to do, it turns out you have to add the parameters to the URL directly. So for the request in the OP,

```
jasmine.Ajax.stubRequest('MY_URL.json?param1=value1')
  .andReturn({
    "status": 200,
    "contentType": 'application/json',
    "responseText": rawData
  });
```